# EditText view resizeing when using "setText" instead of keyboard input

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, image-resizing, tablerow

I have a table layout with 2 EditText in the first 2 rows, and a bunch of buttons working like a custom keyboard in the other rows. (just included only the first row of buttons in the xml below for simplicity)
EditText views are set as scrollable with `android:scrollbars="vertical"`. When i press a button on my custom keyboard i add the value to an input string and then i set the text with `EditText.setText()` method. My problem is that if text is too long it goes to the next line resizeing the full EditText view too. Otherwise, doing the same with the default android keyboard works like a charm, going on the next line without resizeing and displaying the scroll bar on the right.
**Here's the XML**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dip">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Type an expression to begin..." />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dip">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Real time calculation"/>
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_divide"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

What's the problem with the `setText()` method?
In addition i want to add a background image on both EditText resizeing it to adapt to the view without making EditText resizeing.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: add desired output picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:text="Type an expression to begin...\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n ddfsfs\n\n\n erwr dsf" />
    </ScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#220000" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:text="Real time calculation"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cross"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cross"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_divide"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cross"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cross"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you man. You made my day. Can you explain me why i wouldn't have used TableLayout insted of LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dip">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Type an expression to begin..." />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dip">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Real time calculation"/>
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_divide"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom_bg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Use this will solve your issue.